# Operator norm of $P[v]-P[w]$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal H$ be a complex Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\mid\rangle$, (dirac notation) which is semi-linear (conjugate linear) in the first argument. Let $\mathcal P_1=\mathcal P_1 (\mathcal H)$ denote the set of *rank one* and *self-adjoint projections* on $\mathcal H$, i.e.

$$\mathcal P_1=\{P[v]:v \in \mathcal H, \|v\|=1\}.$$

where $P[v]$ refers to the projection with precise range $\mathbb C\cdot v$. Since projections are operators on $\mathcal H$ the operator norm defines a metric on $\mathcal P_1$: $d(P[v],P[w])=\|P[v]-P[w]\|$.

I'm trying to prove that the following is true:

$$\|P[v]-P[w]\|=\sqrt{1-|\langle v\mid w\rangle|^2}=\sqrt{1-\operatorname{Tr}P[v]P[w]}.$$

What I know so far is that $\|P[v]\|=1$, and that $\operatorname{Tr}P[v]P[w]=|\langle v\mid w\rangle|^2$ on separable Hilbert spaces as one can choose a Hilbert basis $\{|e_i\rangle\}_{i \in \Bbb N}$, and write the identity operator $I=\sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|$. Then

$$\operatorname{Tr}P[v]P[w]=\langle v\mid w\rangle\operatorname{Tr}(|v\rangle\langle w|)=\langle v\mid w\rangle \sum_i \langle e_i\mid v\rangle\langle w\mid e_i\rangle =\langle v\mid w\rangle \sum_i \langle w\mid e_i\rangle\langle e_i\mid v\rangle=\langle v\mid w\rangle  \langle w|\left(\sum_i|e_i\rangle\langle e_i|\right)|v\rangle=|\langle v\mid w\rangle|^2.$$

One problem is I'm not sure how that holds for non-separable spaces, but the actual problem I'm having is calculating the operator norm above.

I also know that for a self adjoint operator $A$ that $$\|A\|^2=\|A^2\|.$$
Now this would be useful for introducing the square root but then I need to calculate $$\|P[v]+P[w]-P[v]P[w]-P[w]P[v]\|.$$

One last thing that's supposed to be useful for calculating operator norms or so a set of notes says is that: $$\|A\|=\sup_{\|v\|=1} |\langle A(v)|v\rangle|.$$

I can't quite piece this all together however.

Comment: Note that this is a two-dimensional problem. Let $F = \operatorname{span} \{v,w\}$, and decompose $\mathcal{H} = F \oplus F^\perp$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So I can write vectors uniquely as $u=u_{F}+u_{F}^{\perp}$. And then I need only consider the action of the operators on $F$. And there's two cases where they're linearly independent and when they're not?

Comment: Yes, and the case of linear dependence is trivial, then we have $P[v] = P[w]$. So look at $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the standard inner product, assume $v = e_1$, and write $w = \alpha\cdot e_1 + \beta\cdot e_2$ with $\lvert\alpha\rvert^2 + \lvert \beta\rvert^2 = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So actually any vector in $F$ is an eigenvector of $P[v]+P[w]-P[v]P[w]-P[w]P[v]$ with eigenvalue $1-|\alpha\mid^2$, which is $1-|\langle v \mid w \rangle \mid^2$? In which case I would be done from earlier arguments.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Also thank you for the edit

Comment: That's correct, on $F$, $(P[v] - P[w])^2$ is $1 - \lvert\langle v\mspace{-3mu}\mid\mspace{-3mu} w\rangle\rvert$ times the identity. On $F^\perp$ it is of course $0$.